# How can I create a vector with values that are obtained by a function that returns different values for every row?

Tags: r, apply

I have a function `club_points(club)` that returns me the total points of the `club`. Now I want to make a data frame with `club` on the rows and the `club_points` values of the respective `club` in the columns. Is there a way to iterate my function in order to automatically assign the points in the same row as the club?
After some research I believe I have to use the apply family... but since I am new I dont know how to do it

```
               teams        total_points

    1         Rio Ave            0
    2      Moreirense            0
    3       Sp Lisbon            0
    4         Tondela            0
    5        Boavista            0
    6       Guimaraes            0
    7         Setubal            0
    8         Estoril            0
    9      Belenenses            0
    10         Chaves            0
    11       Maritimo            0
    12 Pacos Ferreira            0
    13          Porto            0
    14         Arouca            0
    15        Benfica            0
    16       Feirense            0
    17       Sp Braga            0
    18       Nacional            0
```

this the current format of my dataframe `final_pos`, but i would like to iterate the `club_points` function in the `total_points` column

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```
final_pos$total_points <- Vectorize(club_points, "club")(final_pos$teams)
```

or

```
final_pos$total_points <- sapply(final_pos$teams,club_points)
```

Comment: both gave me this error: Error in Ops.factor(visitor, club) : level sets of factors are different

Comment: @JoãoMachado Is `final_pos$teams` of type `factor`? If so, you may need to use `as.character(final_pos$teams)` instead in above code

Comment: I am using this line: `final_pos$total_points <- apply(final_pos, 1, club_points)` and it is returning some values, not the correct ones, but some values at least. But I know for a fact that my function is returning the values correctly because I tested separately

Comment: @JoãoMachado I have no idea what happens if you do not provide any data you are using....

Comment: It worked! Yes it was  `factor`... I cant use apply family functions with factors?

Comment: I mean (and sorry for the noob questions), whats the difference between: `final_pos$total_points <- apply(final_pos, 1, club_points)` and `final_pos$total_points <- sapply(as.character(final_pos$teams),club_points)`

Comment: @JoãoMachado of course you can do with `apply`, but should be `final_pos$total_points <- apply(as.character(final_pos$teams), 2, club_points)`

Comment: It returned this: `Error in apply(as.character(final_pos$teams), 1, club_points) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length`

Comment: @JoãoMachado Note that `2` is in `apply`, not `1`

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! If it isnt to much problem, do you know how can I arrange the table so the first row corresponds to the club with the most points? I dont want to order just the column, i want to change the index...

Comment: @JoãoMachado try `final_pos[order(final_pos$total_points, decreasing = TRUE),]`

Comment: it worked but the indexes stayed the same.... dont if it is possible. Like the order is now sorted by descendent way, which is nice and I can see the standings of the team, but the indexes are the previous ones

Comment: @JoãoMachado what indexes? you mean the the row number?

Comment: @JoãoMachado you need to update the row numbers manually, i.e., `rownames(final_pos) <- seq(nrow(final_pos))`